# C# Click html submit button with no id

Tags: c#

I have a page in my C# webbrowser that contains

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign out">
```

Since it does not have an id, I am unable to use the webbrowser's htmldocument to get it by an id and invoke its click. How would I click it using htmldocument now?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it your own ID you know, it's doesn't have to be a server control for that.  Just do:

```
<input type="submit" ID="MySubmitButton1" value="Sign out">
```

You mention you want to call something when it is clicked, alternatively just add the onclick event manually:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="CallMyFunction()" value="Sign out">
```

Pass 'this' into it if you want to pass the input control into the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="CallMyFunction(this)" value="Sign out">
```

You probably don't want the submit button to post anything when you call your function as well, so you probably want something like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return CallMyFunction()" value="Sign out">

function CallMyFunction()
{
    bool IsFormValid = false;

    // Check if form is valid

    return IsFormValid;
}
```

Comment: @Anon, no problem glad I could help.  Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have control over the HTML page and therefore cannot add an ID to the element, you could use the [`HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) to get all input elements, and then filter that collection by the `type` and `value` attributes. Something like:

```
var firstMatchingSubmit = (from input in myDocument.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                           where input.GetAttribute("type") == "submit" &&
                                 input.GetAttribute("value") == "Sign out"
                           select input).FirstOrDefault();
if (firstMatchingSubmit != null) 
{
    firstMatchingSubmit.RaiseEvent("click");
}
```

Note that this approach is not appropriate if there are multiple matching elements (only the first one will be clicked).

Comment: Quite possibly, didn't try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
webbrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
```

Answer (score 0):

How to handle page with multiple html submit button with no id? How to identify the submit button from 2nd row.[Multiple html buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKjeH.png)

[image: html code]

Comment: Is this an answer?